# Is there a standard name for the groups $SL(n,\mathbb Z)$ or $GL(n,\mathbb Z)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, terminology, integer-lattices, unimodular-matrices

Is there a standard name for the set of all $n\times n$ integer matrices with determinant $1$ (special linear) or $\pm1$ (general linear)?

The matrices themselves are called "[unimodular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unimodular_matrix)", but apparently "[unimodular group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haar_measure#The_modular_function)" means something else.

"Integer special linear group"? I've never heard that.

"Lattice automorphism group"?

Comment: https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Special_linear_group_over_integers

Comment: What's wrong with "essellenzed" (or "essellenzee" if you prefer)? That's what I call it, and everyone knows what I mean.